# Вывести содержимое бд в листвью

Tags: android, sqlite

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как вывести содержимое бд в листвью.
Я смотрел уроки в интернете, но везде вывод только в логи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Урок 136. CursorLoader](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html)